# Removing quotes from string

Tags: perl, string

So I thought this would just be a simple issue however I'm getting the incorrect results. Basically I am trying to remove the quotes around a string. For example I have the string "01:00" and I want 01:00, below is the code on how I thought I would be able to do this:

```
$expected_start_time = $conditions =~ m/(\"[^\"])/;
```

Every time this runs it returns 1, so I'm guessing that it is just returning true and not actually extracting the string from the quotes. This happen no matter what is in the quotes "02:00", "02:20", "08:00", etc.

Comment: Most quoting will provide a means of escaping (e.g. `\"`), and sometimes even special escapes (e.g. `\x20`). None of the solutions handle this, so all of them are unlikely to be correct. But you did not provide sufficient information to do any better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All you forgot was parens for the LHS to put the match into list context so it returns the submatch group(s). The normal way to do this is:

```
 ($expected_start_time) = $condition =~ /"([^"]*)"/;
```

Answer (score 15):

It appears that you know that the first and last character are quotes. If that is the case, use

```
$expected_start_time = substr $conditions, 1, -1;
```

No need for a regexp.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. why did this get downvoted? Ain't it more performant than the =~ regex? anyway it works and feels more sober, so vote up from me

Answer (score 5):

The brute force way is:

```
$expected_start_time = $conditions;
$expected_start_time =~ s/"//g;
```

Note that the original regex:

```
m/(\"[^\"])/
```

would capture the opening quote and the following non-quote character.  To capture the non-quote characters between double quotes, you'd need some variant on:

```
m/"([^"]*)"/;
```

This being Perl (and regexes), TMTOWTDI - There's More Than One Way Do It.

Comment: Brandon: '"' isn't a special character and does not need to be quoted, although there is no harm in doing so.

Comment: @Brandon: No - I meant what I wrote.  Inside a regex, quotes don't have a special meaning.

Comment: But there's no harm is escaping all non-alphanumerics with a backslash.  I often do it even when it's not required so I can't tell at a glance it's not a meta-character.

Answer (score 1):

In scalar context a regex returns true if the regex matches the string. You can access the match with `$1`. See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).