# getting a string with quotes

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string `"Hello" hello` (including the quotes) and i just want to get the Hello that has the quotes but without the quotes

i tried using regular expression but it never finds the quotes im guessing

```
String s = new String("string");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"])\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(n);
    while (m.find()) {
      s = m.group(1);
    }
```

the while loop never gets executed, suggestions?

Comment: Boy, this is sure [similar to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745562/removing-quotes-from-string/5745625#5745625)!

Comment: It's a regex question, they are all similar! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-- Moved the star inside the parenthesis for proper grouping ---

```
"\"([^\"]*)\""
```

Tested successfully with the code

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = new String("\"Hello\" hello");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

which produced the expected output

```
Hello
```

-- Original post follows --

You don't match anything because your regex is written to only match quoted one character strings.

```
"\"([^\"])*\""
```

is closer to what you need.  Note the star, it means zero or more of the preceeding expression.  In this case the preceeding expression is "anything that lacks a double quote".

Comment: made those changes and the while loop still does not happen

Comment: Did you try against the string you posted?  `String s = new String("string");` doesn't contain any quotes (despite how it is written).  `String s = new String("\"Hello\" hello");` does contain quotes.

Comment: Also, you'd be better off with the * inside the capturing group, like so **"\"([^\"]*)\""**. This way you can actually get at the contents inside the quotes

Comment: @Java Drinker, just noticed that as I wrote up a quick test class to see why tyczj was still having problems.  Post is already updated.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you try a String which has quotes in it if you want to find any. ;)

Try

```
String s = "start  \"string\" end";
```

or

```
String s = "\"Hello\" hello";
```

Comment: He posted the contents of the string, so to get the quotes in it, they were already escaped.  The issue is with the regex, not the string.

Comment: +1: Looks like it's a two problem issue, the string and the regex!

Comment: A common mistake to forget the `"` at the start and end are not part of the string. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `indexOf("\"")` in this case.