# decoding perl regexp =~ s/"//g

Tags: regex, perl

can you help me decode this regex in perl?

```
$results=~ s/"//g;
```

Comment: Your regex is very simple. It's just the single character `"` which matches a single close quote character. You use the regex in a substitution operator (`s/.../.../`) which replaces whatever matches the regex with the second argument (which is an empty string). You also use the `/g` option which makes the substitution global - i.e. it matches all double-quote characters and replaces each one with an empty string. You then apply that substitution to the variable `$results`.

Comment: To other ways to unquote from a string, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745562/removing-quotes-from-string). (This question was closed as a duplicate of this questions, but none of the answers to that questions come remotely close to answering this question.)

Answer (score 1):

The only regex pattern in that code is `"`. Absent any special meaning, a character matches itself. And `"` are not special in regex patterns. So that regex pattern matches `"`.

That Perl statement as a whole removes all `"` characters from the string in `$results`. The substitution operator (`s///`) is used to repeatedly (`g`) find double-quotes (`"`) and replace them with nothing.

`s///` is documented in [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop).
Regex patterns are documented in [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre).